# Power Automate Error On Specific Web Page: "error in communication with browser"

Tags: google-chrome, quickbooks, power-automate, quickbooks-online, rpa

I am running into an error message in Power Automate that says "error in communication with browser" when attempting to perform any web page actions, such as filling in a text field, specifically on the website [https://qbo.intuit.com](https://qbo.intuit.com/).

Initially, I thought the issue was Power Automate communicating with the web browser but then I programmed it to go to Google.com and found that I was able to type text in Google's search bar.

That confirmed that the issue is specific to the web form used on [https://qbo.intuit.com](https://qbo.intuit.com/).

Can anyone, in Google Chrome, try going to [https://www.qbo.intuit.com](https://qbo.intuit.com/) and see if they can have Power Automate fill in the "Username" field.

If you are able to, please let me know how you were able to do it and possibly post the flow so that I can see it as I am relatively new to Power Automate.

However, I am not new to RPA as I use UiPath on a daily basis. I have not seen this issue in UiPath before.

Comment: that site is not reachable at all.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had to take "www" out of the url for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue on that particular URL. As you are well verse with UIPath i am assuming you are doing things correctly. If you click on error, further details tells that this could be extension error.

Try to reinstall the extension and PAD itself. This may or may not solve your problem. Check these links for any help. [PAD Browser Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/using-browsers), [Error with Browser](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/Not-able-to-click-on-the-Button/td-p/757625)

However, if your aim is to populate that form field with some text, you can leverage Javascript function feature from PAD.

Search for `Run JavaScript function on web page` action in left pane. Drag-drop it after Web page load action and put the below code in Javascript function. Element id you can get by `Inspect` feature from browser

```
document.getElementById('ius-userid').value = <Your input goes here>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gandalf I will try the JavaScript activity.

Comment: I just needed to use the JavaScript activity as described above and it worked.